# How to implement sin() in a swift made calculator?

Tags: swift, math, implementation, trigonometry

I'm making a calculator and have decided to add some more operations than the standard 4. In trying to implement sin and cos I have run into the following problem.

```
 @IBAction func evaluate(sender: AnyObject) {
    secondNumber = Int(Screen.text!)!
    if operation == "+" {
        result = firstNumber + secondNumber
    } else if operation == "-" {
        result = firstNumber - secondNumber
    } else if operation == "X" {
        result = firstNumber * secondNumber
    } else if operation == "/" {
        result = firstNumber / secondNumber
    } else if operation == "%" {
        result = firstNumber % secondNumber
    } else if operation == "^" {
        result = firstNumber^secondNumber
    } else if operation == "Sin" {
        result = sin(degToRad(Double(firstNumber)))
    }
```

where degToRad is defined as

```
func degToRad(degrees: Double) -> Double {
// M_PI is defined in Darwin.C.math
return M_PI * 2.0 * degrees / 360.0
```

}

I get the following error on the sin line.

"Ambiguous reference to the member "sin""

Why is this occuring and how do I go about using sin? I've imported Darwin so I do not believe that is the issue, I'm still very new to swift so i'm sure i'm doing something easy incorrect but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try self.sin ?
(it might be a scope problem)

Comment: how is your result declare?

Answer (score 1):

If, as @zazu suggests, it's a scoping problem, you can clarify the scoping with:

```
result = Foundation.sin(...)
```

Comment: `Darwin.sin` also works, but `Foundation.sin` will work regardless of platform, where `Darwin.sin` probably won't work on non-Darwin platforms, ie., Linux and Windows.

Comment: It is also true, though, that we need to know how `result` is declared. Unfortunately the OP has hung up the phone...